# Adding extra headings and line seperators between baposter boxes

Tags: posters, baposter

I'm using the [baposter template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/baposter-template/fjrfjwqcpyzq) for a large cheat sheet and I'd like to put sections and subsections between the boxes with some visual separators, similar to how it is done in [this template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/an-unofficial-trb-poster-template-for-southwest-jiaotong-university/qzrbzrbgkmtj). It seems it's not possible to do this with `\sections` and `\hline` in baposter. Is there some other way to add headings in between boxes? Even better if it works with really stylish ones, like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/623828/customizing-chapter-heading-by-adding-box-and-text) I found in my search for related questions. Or is this better done with a different poster template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to stylise the baposter boxes with an empty headerbox in a way that they look like simple section headings:

```
\headerbox{}{
    name=section,
    column=0,
    below=references,
    boxheaderheight=0mm,
    boxColorOne=black,
    borderColor=white, 
    headershape=rectangle, 
    boxshade=None, 
    textborder=None,
    headerColorOne=white,
    headerborder=None
}{
\begin{center}
\bf\textsc Introduction
\end{center}
}
```

[image]

```
\headerbox{}{
    name=subsection,
    column=0,
    below=methods,
    boxheaderheight=0mm,
    borderColor=black, 
    headershape=rectangle, 
    boxshade=None, 
    textborder=None,
}{
\bf\textsc Introduction
}
```

[image]